# Stop Rails generating spec tests for views and helpers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Is there a way to do this from the application.rb?

Answer (score 81, accepted):

**edit:** short answer on top

If you want to do this for *every* time you run the generators, you do indeed customize it within your application.rb file. Put this code in the file inside the Application class definition.

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.view_specs false
  g.helper_specs false
end
```

You can also accomplish this by passing some options into the generator command. [This](http://railscasts.com/episodes/216-generators-in-rails-3) Railscast goes over the process in more detail, but the basic idea is pretty simple.

Rails generators can take several options. You can see the options for the controller generator by running `rails g controller -h`. Assuming you have Rspec set up already, if you look at the output, you notice a section that says "Rspec options". It looks like this:

```
Rspec options:
  [--controller-specs]  # Indicates when to generate controller specs
                        # Default: true
  [--view-specs]        # Indicates when to generate view specs
                        # Default: true
```

To negate these boolean values, just pass them in with a "no" in front of the name. So if you wanted a controller with no specs for your view, you would call it like this:

```
rails g controller Foobar index show new create --no-view-specs
```

And you would get a controller with the correct views and actions created for you, but no specs for your views.

The same thing applies if you are using the `scaffold` generator. There is a `--helper-specs` option, so if you wanted no view or helper specs you would run:

```
rails g scaffold Foobar name:string --no-helper-specs --no-view-specs
```

Comment: You can read more about generators here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html

Comment: Many kudos to you sir! The link above to guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html does not explain this. Nor does the --help option from the command line. No where does it seem to explain that you can merely add `no-` to the options to disable them.