# Syntax to skip creating tests, assets & helpers for `rails generate controller`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, generator

I read the help & tried the following command to skip generation of tests, assets & helper files

```
$ bin/rails generate controller home index  --helper false --assets false --controller-specs false --view-specs false   
create- app/controllers/home_controller.rb
        route  get "home/index"
        invoke  erb
        create    app/views/home
        create    app/views/home/index.html.erb
        invoke  rspec
        error  false [not found]
        error  false [not found]
```

As you may notice by output above this works & only `controller, routes` & `views` are generated.  But as last two lines are interesting:

```
error  false [not found]
error  false [not found]
```

Obviously rails doesn't seem to like `--option-name false` syntax. so this this error because I used the wrong syntax? If yes, then what is the correct way? Thanks

Answer (score 170, accepted):

Try using `--no-` followed by `optionname`:

```
rails generate controller home index  --no-helper --no-assets --no-controller-specs --no-view-specs
```

If you want to change the default behavior every time you run the generator command, you can configure the defaults you would like in the application.rb file - see [How can I make sure Rails doesn't generate spec tests for views and helpers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4235264/how-can-i-make-sure-rails-doesnt-generate-spec-tests-for-views-and-helpers).

Comment: You can also use `skip` instead of `no`, e.g. `--skip-assets`

Answer (score 78):

To turn off without having to add options:

```
# application.rb
config.generators.assets = false
config.generators.helper = false
```

Answer (score 51):

Applications which serve only API will not require `javascript`, `stylesheet`, `views`, `helpers`. To skip those files in generator/scaffold for `Rails 3.x` add the below code block in the `application.rb`

```
#to skip assets, scaffolds.css, test framework, helpers, view
config.generators do |g|
  g.template_engine nil #to skip views
  g.test_framework  nil #to skip test framework
  g.assets  false
  g.helper false
  g.stylesheets false
end
```

check the link for more details about  [generators](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html)

Comment: The above works if you use `false` instead of `nil`.

Comment: It works but you will receive a deprecation warning as of Rails 6 when using false, so it's better to use nil.

Answer (score 34):

More concisely:

```
rails g controller home index --no-assets --no-test-framework
```

Answer (score 4):

Inside application.rb file write: This will stop generating everything apart from what is written in the command line

```
config.generators do |g|
  g.test_framework nil
  g.template_engine nil
  g.assets false
  g.helper false
  g.stylesheets false
  g.javascripts false
end
```

Example:

```
vidur@vidur-desktop:~/Downloads/tukaweb$ rails g controller uploader/three_d_models 
Running via Spring preloader in process 3703
      create  app/controllers/uploader/three_d_models_controller.rb
      invoke  assets
      invoke    js
      invoke    scss
```

for one liner solution =>

```
rails g controller assets_garments --skip-test-framework --skip-assets --skip-helper
```

Answer (score 2):

### If you want to generate only controller, nothing else.

```
rails g controller [controller_name] [index] --no-helper --no-assets --no-template-engine --no-test-framework
```