# Stop script/generate model from making test files

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails2, I want to stop the `script/generate model MyModel` from generating the `test/fixtures/my_model.yml` and the `test/unit/my_model.rb`. Is there any way I can modify the `config/application.rb` file or the `script/generate` file to stop these two files from being generated?

I don't want to add options to the `script/generate model MyModel` command to accomplish this

Comment: duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14045858/rails-generator-syntax-to-skip-tests-assets-helpers ?

Comment: I don't want to add options after the command to accomplish this. I want to change a file somewhere that will automatically block these files from being gnerated.

Answer (score 1):

Then something like this should work:

```
config.generators.assets = false
config.generators.helper = false
config.generators.view_specs = false
```

More here: https://robots.thoughtbot.com/reduce-application-clutter-disable-unwanted-rails

Edit: added a source link

Comment: Is there any way to do this same sort of thing in Rails 2?